# Display Carousel as half image slider

Tags: iphone, javascript, html, css

i want to display carousel as half image slider instead of full page slider.

CSS:

```
html,
body {
height: 40%;
margin: auto;
 }

header.carousel {
height: 40%;
margin:auto;
}

header.carousel .item,
header.carousel .item.active,
header.carousel .carousel-inner {
height: 40%;
margin:auto;
}

header.carousel .fill {
width: 100%;
height: 40%;

background-size:cover ;
margin: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <!--first slide-->
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="image/stylegirl.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="carousel-caption">

                <h1 class="toggleCaption">Text Test</h1>

                <div class="toggleButton">
    <p><a class="btn btn-default-outline btn-lg" role="button"> Test Button</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>



        <!--second slide-->
        <div class="item">
            <img src="image/couple.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="carousel-caption">

                <h1 class="toggleCaption">Test Text</h1>

                <div class="toggleButton">
      <p><a class="btn btn-default-outline btn-lg" role="button">Test Button</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>


        <!--Third Slide-->
        <div class="item">
            <img src="image/w1.jpg" style="Width:100%">
            <div class="carousel-caption">

                <h1 class="toggleCaption">Test Text</h1>

                <div class="toggleButton">
      <p><a class="btn btn-default-outline btn-lg" role="button"> Test Button</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>


    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</header>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yomozon/71acwbe3/)

Image is missing from the fiddle coz i don't know how to add image from the local file.

It shows half slider image only when i use height in px instead of %.
But still it is showing as full page slider carousel. Why is that.

Any help.

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML please?

Comment: And relevant javascript? Please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.org)

Comment: why dont you try .carousel-inner{width:50%}?

Comment: it was 50% but didn't showed as half slider so changed it to 40%

Comment: that is why we need a fiddle, to appropriately answer your question. It shouldnt be 40%